# Preview not displaying identical to final post

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

I just posted the question [Using collcell package with csvsimple, or datatool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82682/using-collcell-package-with-csvsimple-or-datatool).  After posting it looks like the formatting of the two error messages is not identical:

[image: actual post]

---

But, when I go to edit it what I see in the preview is identical preview for the second case, but not for the first case:

[image: preview]

Comment: Great question. `:)` The same happens with the `spoiler` syntax, as seen in [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63732/cute-document-in-latex).

Comment: Looking on the source the bug in my opinion is in the edit preview.

Comment: +1, even though it doesn't look like you're using markdown in a way that it is supposed/expected to be used?!

Comment: @doncherry: You mean in terms of using the `>`?  What is the _official_ way of quoting errors?

Comment: @Speravir: Yep, I thought it best to leave so that the SE programmers can use it as a test case to see if the updates fix the display in preview mode.

Comment: If you paste the error as is, select all of it, then click the code markup button, and then the block quote button, you get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IfvbT.png

Comment: @doncherry: Wow, you may find this hard to believe but I have _never_ noticed the block quote button? :-) Have always added the `>` manually.. Now that I know, that I can ask even more questions as it will now take me less time. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help `:)`. Another tip, in case you didn't know: You can also use Ctrl+K for code and Ctrl+Q for block quotes.

Comment: @doncherry: Excellent... So much faster...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting edge case, and one where [various Markdown implementations disagree](http://babelmark.bobtfish.net/?markdown=%3E+%0D%0A++++x). That leaves the call to me, and I think the server-side version did the more correct thing here, so [I've changed the preview](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=c06c6e0d465e2639398c32b0a24a9e4b89503e7a) to behave the same way. This fix is in the next build of the sites.